# How to convert .lbl file to ZPL code or String, so I can change it's variables?

Tags: android-studio, zebra-printers

I'm searching for a solution or documentation, which will help me to convert any .lbl file into somethink I can modify. I have constanly changing .lbl file so I can't use same ZPL code every time, like I do in other apps.

Comment: You can print your lbl to prn with Zebra Designer. Or didnt you mean this?

Comment: @etalon11 hello, it's kinda old problem, but I want to import .lbl file with into my mobile app. Then I want to convert it into string containing ZPL code and than I want to replace ceratain characters with strings inputed by user in app from edittext. Later I'm sending this ZPL string to printer and I get my label with my own text from app. I would just use the same ZPL code every time, but It's variables are constanly changing. Sometimes it's the matter of graphics or just a code. But it's not always the same.